# How to initiate Firebase Phone Verification through an API

Tags: php, firebase, authentication

We have to have phone auth through Firebase on our mobile apps for a project. But there will also be variants that will not have the said phone auth.

As there is a centralized API too, it would be best that the verification is initiated through it, instead of the apps. But I have not found any help towards that end in their docs.

If that's not possible, is there a way to verify said verification through the API or if there is some web-hook service available?

Comment: When creating a user through one of the Admin SDKs, the Firebase API will reject invalid phone numbers. There is no official Admin SDK for PHP, but an unofficial one exists at https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php (see https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-management.html#create-a-user). It will not verify the phone number though, as this is done by authenticating through the number itself. If it's not reachable or doesn't belong to the user, they will not be able to authenticate.

Comment: @jeromegamez Actually I have seen implementations of this at different third party services which take the firebase phone verification credentials and verify them through their APIs. Thus, it does seem that either a solution exists or they have reverse engineered the available SDKs. Essentially those SDKs after all wrap an API, which is nothing too far fetched in that regard.